# How to do pass-thru uploads to s3 on Heroku with node.js?

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

Here's my current code.  I'm using express and knox, and I don't think I'm doing anything unusual, but `s3.putFile` is responding 400 status code but null error, and the file does not get uploaded.

```
var express = require('express');
var knox = require('knox');

var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());

var s3 = knox.createClient({
    key: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secret: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    var photo = req.files.photo;
    var s3Headers = {
      'Content-Type': photo.type,
      'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
    };

    s3.putFile(photo.path, photo.name, s3Headers, function(err, s3response){
      //handle, respond
    });
});
```

This same code works fine even from the [cloud9](https://c9.io) online editor/debugger, just not from Heroku.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the "[ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)", but that's just a guess.  However I was able to get s3 pass-thru uploads to work on Heroku in Clojure using [noir](http://webnoir.org/) and [weavejester's aws sdk](https://github.com/weavejester/clj-aws-s3), so it must be possible in node as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled across a fix—once I added the following to `package.json`, it started working.  Heroku defaults to 0.4 otherwise.

```
"engines": {
  "node": "0.8.x"
}
```